# How to rename the file from external storage (Sdcard)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have been trying to rename the file from external storage (Sdcard) using below code.But not rename the file, **boolean** return the false value.This code working fine for internal storage (Phone memory)

`File f1= new File(sdcard_current_path);
 File f2= new File(sdcard_rename_path); 
 boolean isSuccess=f1.renameTo(f2);`

Comment: Did you added external storage permissions?

Comment: do you have add the storage permissions?

Comment: Already added Read and Write Permission to AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

Make sure is directory present in storage.
you can use the following code

```
File f1= new File(sdcard_current_path, filename);
File f2= new File(sdcard_rename_path, newfilname); 
boolean isSuccess=f1.renameTo(f2);
```

Comment: have you given run time permission for READ & WRITE external storage ?

Comment: Already added Read and Write Permission to AndroidManifest.xml. Working fine internal storage,but not working external storage. I am trying to kitkat 4.4.2 version (Samsung SM-G355H Galaxy Core 2 device). This device no runtime permission

Answer (score 0):

First add this line to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then use your code.

Comment: Already added Read and Write Permission to AndroidManifest.xml. working fine internal storage.

Comment: Are you trying to test on a device with android 6 or above? if yes you should use runtime permision

Comment: No, I am trying to kitkat 4.4.2 version (Samsung SM-G355H Galaxy Core 2 device)

Answer (score 0):

To use function renameTo() your source and destination should be on same mount point see android doc https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#renameTo(java.io.File)

[image]

Hope it will help you to resolve the issue.